# How do I use a certificate and the certificate key to authenticate a url?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on sending some randomly generated data to a SAP iot cloud platform. However, due to a version update my old code is no longer valid. I am working on the new code however, I do not know how to use a certificate and the certificate to authenticate a url that is to be opened. Really would appreciate if I can get some help from here. I need some way to use the certificate and its key to authenticate the opening of the url.

config_1 is a separate .py file that hold data such as device ID, certificate path, its key etc.

```
def main():

        try:
                urllib3.disable_warnings()
        except:
                print("attempt failed")

        if (config_1.proxy_url == ''):
                http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        else:
                default_headers = make_headers(basic_auth=config_1.proxy_user_credentials)

                http = ProxyManager(config_1.proxy_url, headers=default_headers)

                url='CLOUD PLATFORM URL' + str(config_1.device_id)


        headers = urllib3.util.make_headers(user_agent=None)
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        send_to_hcp(http,url,headers)


def send_to_hcp(http,url,headers):
    global s1

    while True:

        vibration = round(random.uniform(3,50),2)
        temperature = round(random.uniform(3,20),2)
        lux = round(random.uniform(3,30),2)

        body = '{"capabilityAlternateId":' +config_1.config_capabilityAlternateId +',"sensorAlternateId":' +config_1.config_sensorAlternateId +', \
            "measures":[{"vibration":'+ str(vibration) + ',"temp":' + str(temperature) + ', "lux":' + str(lux) + '}]}'

        r = http.urlopen('POST', url, body=body, headers=headers)

        print(r.status)

        if (debug_communication == 1):
            print (body)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "authenticate a URL". Are you just trying to establish an HTTPS connection with the server? Are you trying to provide client authentication *to* the server?

Comment: yes i want to provide client authentication to the server using certificates and keys.